# Unable to inject errors with Einj (mce-test, ras-tools)

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

I want to inject memory errors on my system to check whether RAS/EDAC system really works and logs errors on my memory (during boot or any runtime). I came across with many tools but I don't know which one to actually trust. The machine I want to test is a Sandy Bridge machine running Linux kernel 5.15.0-58-generic version. Specificially, I want to test my system with Einj tool (https://docs.kernel.org/firmware-guide/acpi/apei/einj.html). Although I followed the earlier steps in the link (BIOS supports Einj, CONFIG_DEBUG_FS, CONFIG_ACPI_APEI, CONFIG_ACPI_APEI_EINJ config parameters are set on my kernel), the files mentioned in the document: /sys/kernel/debug/apei/einj etc. are not present. How can I proceed with this tool? Or is there a better way/tool to inject memory errors to check the EDAC subsystem?